# point of symmetry of the graph of a function

Tags: graphing-functions

the graph of the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{2x}{1+x^2}+\cdots+\frac{2^{n-1}x^{2^{n-1}-1}}{1+x^{2^{n-1}}}+\cdots$$  where $x \in (-1,1)$ is symmetric about the point---

I tried to integrate the function and could not proceed to find centre of symmetry.I tried it in desmos and i got the [following curve](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kvjho1rvte).Please help me out.Thanks

Comment: Are you interpreting the point of symmetry in the standard sense?

Comment: For $n>1$, $f(x)$ is neither odd nor even.  For $n=1$, the singular point $x=-1$ is centre of 2-fold rotational symmetry.  None of other symmetrical point is observed.

Comment: Without the first term $1/(1+x)$ every partial sums and the limit are odd functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly $f(x)$ is a very simple function as shown below. To get it, we start from :

$F_0(x)=(1+x)$

$F_1(x)=(1+x)(1+x^2)=(1+x)+x^2(1+x)=1+x+x^2+x^3$

$\begin{cases}
F_2(x)=(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)=(1+x^2+x^3)+x^4(1+x^2+x^3) \\
F_2(x)=1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7
\end{cases}$

and so on ...

$\begin{cases}
F_n(x)=(1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^{(2^n)}) \\
F_n(x)=1+x+x^2+...+x^{(2^{n+1}-1)}
\end{cases}$
$$F_n(x)=\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n}(1+x^{(2^k)})=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n+1}-1}x^k=\frac{1-x^{(2^{n+1})}}{1-x}$$
$$\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}(1+x^{(2^k)})=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
$$\ln\left(\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}(1+x^{(2^k)})\right) =\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\ln(1+x^{(2^k)})=-\ln(1-x)$$ 
The differentiation leads to :
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^kx^{(2^k)-1} }{1+x^{(2^k)}}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
We recognize $f(x)$ :
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
All above is valid for $-1<x<1$. So, $f(x)$ is an arc of hyperbola.

Obviously, the symmetry is with respect to the straight line $y=1-x$ with center $(x=0\:,\:y=1)$.

[image]

This is in good agreement with your own graph (magnified) :

[image]

Comment: Actuallythe graph is *not* symmetric over $(-1,1)$ as one arm goes to infinity, while the other arm ends at $-1$. The graph of the restriction of $f$ to $(-1,\frac12)$ is symmetric, though.

Comment: @cellschk : I agree. In fact, I mean the symmetry of the whole branch of the hyperbola, including the extension of $f$ to $-\infty$ as the dotted line on the figure. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: To the Editors, about the edition suggested : The correction proposed was justified, but not sufficient. I corrected and re-edited all the beginning. This doesn't change the end of the answer. Thank you for pointing out the mess in the beginning.